# "Add Event..." button, why is there?

Tags: time, calendar, events

If you click on top right (by default) on time, you will see calendar. Below calendar there is button "Add Event...", but if you click it, it does nothing.

Why is it there, how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing because there is no GUI calendar application installed.Install evolution (GUI for evolution-data-server calendar).

`sudo apt-get install evolution`

After that it will work.